# Apache (and other services) work on localhost, but not IP address

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, apache2, firewall

My Apache server is working correctly on port 80.

When I try to enable SSL on port 443, I can connect via localhost (telnet localhost 443) but not via IP address (telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 443).

To figure out where the problem is, I took my default port 80 config and changed the references to port 443. Same result. Changed back to 80 and it works fine.

Which leads me to think there's a firewall issue, not a config issue. But I have no firewall rules.

Also this site is working on a virtual machine with same Linux version, 12.04 Precise 64-bit under Virtualbox. I tar the /etc/apache2 directory and put it on the Amazon EC2 instance, I get the behavior described - port 80 works, 443 only localhost.

I'm not an expert, but not a newbie. Stumped half the day, figured time to reach out, maybe others can help/benefit. Am I missing something simple, or is there something new I have to do to open up port 443?

ports.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

default-ssl in sites-enabled

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName mysite.mydomain.com:443
 ... more irrelevant stuff
```

note if I enable only default-ssl and just change 443 to 80, it works

so, that made me think there was no Apache config issue, but some firewall issue. But I have no firewall enabled.

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

nmap localhost vs. the IP address

```
 sudo nmap -sT -O -PN xx.xx.xx.xx

 Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-30 13:53 EDT
 Nmap scan report for ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com (xx.xx.xx.xx)
 Host is up (0.0013s latency).
 Not shown: 996 filtered ports
 PORT     STATE  SERVICE
 22/tcp   open   ssh
 25/tcp   closed smtp
 80/tcp   open   http
 3306/tcp closed mysql
 Device type: general purpose
 Running (JUST GUESSING) : Linux 2.6.X (85%)
 Aggressive OS guesses: Linux 2.6.15 - 2.6.26 (85%)
 No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).

 OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
 Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.56 seconds
 ubuntu@ip-10-68-23-145:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo nmap -sT -O -PN localhost
```

nmap localhost

```
 Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-30 13:53 EDT
 Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
 Host is up (0.000047s latency).
 Not shown: 995 closed ports
 PORT     STATE SERVICE
 22/tcp   open  ssh
 80/tcp   open  http
 443/tcp  open  https
 3306/tcp open  mysql
 9418/tcp open  git
 No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
 TCP/IP fingerprint:
 OS:SCAN(V=5.21%D=7/30%OT=22%CT=1%CU=42076%PV=N%DS=0%DC=L%G=Y%TM=51F7FD9D%P=
 OS:x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)SEQ(SP=FD%GCD=1%ISR=10E%TI=Z%CI=Z%II=I%TS=8)OPS
 OS:(O1=M400CST11NW5%O2=M400CST11NW5%O3=M400CNNT11NW5%O4=M400CST11NW5%O5=M40
 OS:0CST11NW5%O6=M400CST11)WIN(W1=8000%W2=8000%W3=8000%W4=8000%W5=8000%W6=80
 OS:00)ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=8018%O=M400CNNSNW5%CC=Y%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%S=O%A
 OS:=S+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=N)T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%
 OS:Q=)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=
 OS:A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)U1(R=
 OS:Y%DF=N%T=40%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%DFI=N%
 OS:T=40%CD=S)

 Network Distance: 0 hops

 OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
 Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 12.70 seconds



lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your Security Group on [Amazon EC2](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2) and if there is no rule for 443 port, add one.

Comment: Well, I opened up port 443 to all, no luck. I had everything open to all machines in the security group. Also everything open to my remote IP. Still, if I telnet localhost 443 it works, if I telnet <ip address> 443 from the local machine (which is in the same security as itself so you wouldn't expect it to be blocked) or from a remote machine, it times out. Port 80 works in all cases, and as far as I can see they are set up identically. I also added a Name VirtualHost directive to ports.conf so it would be the same as port 80.

Comment: Made ports.conf identical for port 80 and port 443.

    `NameVirtualHost *:80
    Listen 80
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443`

Comment: argh... you're right, I'm wrong.

the server was not in the security group it was supposed to be (test v prod) so the changes I made before had no effect.

the behavior I see is, if I don't open the port in the firewall, I can telnet from the server to localhost or the internal IP, but not the elastic IP. 

This is even though there is a rule that all servers in the same security group should have all access.

Took me a while, but many thanks for the right answer on the first try!