# apache2 on ubuntu 14 - localhost works but ip doesn't

Tags: networking, 14.04, apache2, php, firewall

I've just installed apache2 on my box, along with php5.

I can navigate to "localhost" and it works.  But I can't access this webserver from another machine... or even locally using the IP address.
Other posts such as [Apache (and other services) work on localhost, but not IP address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326617/apache-and-other-services-work-on-localhost-but-not-ip-address) suggest firewall settings and also checking to make sure I'm listening not just on localhost but *80.

This is what I have in ports.conf:

```
me@mydev:/etc/apache2$ cat ports.conf 
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>   Listen 443 </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>     Listen 443 </IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The default firewall doesn't seem to be enabled:

```
me@mydev:/etc/apache2$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for me: 
Status: inactive
me@mydev:/etc/apache2$
```

Just not sure what else I should check.
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

```
Results from IP tables query:

me@mydev:/etc/apache2$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for me: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source              
destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source              
destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source              
destination
me@mydev:/etc/apache2$
```

And I am able to successfully ping the box from different machines.

**EDIT 2**

Here are the results from the nmap command:

```
me@mydev:/var/www/html/test$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-12-01 04:04 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00020s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
631/tcp open  ipp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
me@mydev:/var/www/html/test$
```

And for the IP:

```
me@mydev:/var/www/html/test$ nmap 10.238.59.63

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-12-01 04:08 EST
Nmap scan report for mydev.testdomain.bg.org (10.238.59.63)
Host is up (0.00024s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
me@mydev:/var/www/html/test$
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `sudo iptables -L`. Also try to ping the ip address

Comment: What does 'nmap' gives when you run it on local host and your machines IPv4 address? Do you want to have Apache listening on IPv6? You need to have your Apache to listen to your IPv4 address, or the "listen to all address" address '0.0.0.0'. So it isn't enough to just set the ports you want your Apache to listen for connections on.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but to clear up some confusion... you don't listen on "localhost" or your ip address, you listen only on a port which is on your machine's ip address.  "localhost" is simply a shortcut for your own ip address.   Also, apache will respond to connections from other computers on the lan by default, I believe. What error do you get in the browser when you try to connect?

Comment: @MartyFried I'm getting a connection timed out error message for the site when i try to connect from another machine on the LAN

Comment: @Anders, please see my edit which includes results from "nmap" command

Comment: Ok, that looks ok.  Your apache(?) have port 80 open, I think. Have you looked into the webservers log files in `/var/log/apache2/*`? Use the `tail(1)` command with the switch `-f` to show new lines any time something new come up in any log.  Do that while you access your machine.  Something should turn up in the logs.  So try `tail -f /var/log/apache/*.log` and see if something shows up while you surf to your machine.

Comment: If you uses names and no IP-numbers, use `getent hosts machine.example.com` to resolve the IP-number from the name, in same way the system does.

Answer (score 0):

*This isn't actually an answer, but it was too detailed to be a comment, and may become an answer after more information is determined.*

When I read your post, I thought you were using your lan ip address (internal ip address), but after comparing the results of your commands vs my own, forcing me to look more closely, I see that you are trying to use an external public ip address.

This situation results in more variables and more complexity.

Are you using the actual ip address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), or the domain name?

Is "mydev.testdomain.bg.org" the actual domain name?  I don't see this in the registry at all - how are you getting the DNS?

Does your apache configuration file have the ServerName specified in the VirtualHost setup in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?

What sort of system is this hosted on? I've seen situations with certain routers where you couldn't access a local site from the local machine using the external public ip (for example, Comcast's router).

**EDIT**:   Also, when you make changes to your configuration, as suggested by people who may or may not have a clue about what they are suggesting, and the change does not solve your problem, do you go back and undo the change to restore the original configuration?  You should either do that, or keep very good records about all the changes you've made.

Comment: I'm in fact not using a public IP addy.  It's just an internal address.  The domain name I listed is just a fudge domain.  I'm using the IP Address....  the config file doesn't have a ServerName variable defined.  The machine is just a ubuntu 64 bit desktop.  This is just a test system.

Comment: @dot:  So, why the confusing data?  How did you determine the ip address?

Comment: I did an ifconfig to get the IP address.  Can you expand on why you think it's using an external address - just to put me on the same page? Thanks!

Comment: @dot: Mostly, I was fooled by your data,where you used an external domain name.  I'm not an expert on ip addresses, so it may be a local address, but I'm used to seeing either 192.168.x.x or 10.0.x.x.  I wasn't sure, so that's why I asked.

Comment: @Marty.  Any address starting with 10.x.x.x is a private address. It is actually written 10.0.0.0/8, but that is usually divided into networks with 10.x.x.0./24.  Same for 192.168.0.0/16, which is usually divided in smaller 192.168.x.0/24 nets.

Comment: @Anders:  Thanks, I kind of figured that out but wasn't 100% sure, but the way he first wrote it made me think it was external - bg.org is a real domain name.  The thing is, I've created many web sites both locally and remote, and never had to do anything fancy to get this to work, so something is fishy.

Comment: Usually the router do domain name resolution. So it translate the host name to the private address. And then you use DMZ or port forwarding by your routers public address to your web server and that public address is in your public DNS server.
So same DNS name resolves to different IPv4-addresses depending on where your query from. That's why I asked about what `getent hosts` resolved into. Notice that this will not work with carrier grade NAT, which is coming. :(
No, it's hard to route the public address to the server from the LAN, that is *one* of the hells with NAT. That is solved by IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a VM, **just try restarting it!!**

I had the exact same problem with the same configurations you had in a fresh install of Ubuntu. localhost was working but nothing else. A restart solved it for me.